# How to prove hypothesis with a statistical test

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing

so i need to prove with a statistical test that my hypothesis is true, (chi - square test) . Lets say i have this:

Black = 513 , Blue = 680 And my H0 hypothesis is that majority of the people (so 51% and more) choose Blue over black, i can see it from the numbers that it is true in this case but how can i prove it with the statistical test? I tried something like this but it only assumes the percentage i wrote so 51%

```
obs <- c(513,680)

exp <- c(.49, .51)

chisq.test(obs, p=exp)
```

How can i apply the range 51% and above to the test or what else can i use to prove my hypothesis. (Sorry if it is a dumb question i didnt really work much with statistical tests in my past). Thanks to anyone that can help.

Comment: Do you specifically need a chi-square test here, or are you just trying to prove that the probability of choosing blue is greater than 50%?

Comment: You can't prove a hypothesis with a statistical test. You can find evidence for or against the null hypothesis.

Comment: I was told chi-square would be the best option but basically i only need to prove with some statistical test that the p-Value is more than the significance level of 0.05 so i can accept it

Comment: You could do a chi-square test for whether the proportions of people choosing black and blue are different (in either direction), but I don't believe you can use it to show that people are specifically more likely to choose blue.  Also, if your p-value is greater than your significance level, the correct conclusion would be to fail to reject the null hypothesis, which is likely that people are equally likely to choose black and blue.  The _smaller_ your p-value is, the more evidence you have in support of your alternative hypothesis.

Comment: @llottmanhill Ok, thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 1):

The chi-square goodness-of-fit test you conducted with your R code is whether your sample data is consistent with a null distribution where 49% choose black and 51% choose blue. Based on your hypothesis, you'd be better served with a one-sample test for a proportion.  Let $p$ be the probability that someone chooses blue.  Then, your hypotheses are $H_0: p=0.5$ and $H_1: p > 0.5$.  (Note that a majority is anything greater than 50%, not 51% or greater.)

In R you can use `binom.test` for this.

```r
x <- 680        # number of successes
n <- 680 + 513  # sample size
binom.test(x, n, p = 0.5, alternative = "greater")
```

Also, strictly speaking, you're not "proving" your hypothesis--you're determining how much evidence you have in favor of it as opposed to the null.